# Linear functional and polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $F[x]$ be the subspace of $F^\infty$ spaced by the vectors $1, x, x^2, ... $ Then $F[x]$ contains all the polynomials over $F$.

Prove that if $L$ is any linear functional on $F[x]$ such that

$L(fg) = L(f)L(g)$

Then either $L=0$ or there is a $t$ in $F$ such that $L(f)=f(t)$ for all $f$.

Answer (score 2):

First note that $L(1)=L(1)^2$, i.e. either $L(1)=0$ or $L(1)=1$. But, $L(1)=0$ would imply $L=0$ by multiplicativity, so we can assume $L(1)=1$.

Let $t:=L(x)$. Then we have $L(x^n)=t^n$ and thus
$$L(f)=L(a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\dots)=a_0+a_1t+a_2t^2+\dots=f(t)$$

Comment: Why would $L(1)=0$ imply $L=0$? Isn't $1$ just a basis for $F[x]$? Hence wouldn't $L(1)=0$ just mean that the linear functional maps one of the elements in the basis of $F[x]$ to 0? It does not say anything about $L$ in general right because for all we know, $L(x^n) \neq 0$ for any $n \ge 1$. Also, I don't really get the flow of the second part of the prove. How does $L(1)=1$ imply that there is a $t$ such that $L(x)=t$? By the way what does the $:=$ sign mean?

Comment: $L(f)=L(1\cdot f)=L(1)\cdot L(f)=0$ for all $f$ if $L(1)=0$ and $L$ preserves multiplication.
For the other question, $t:=L(x)$ means '*let $t$ be* $L(x)$'. Note that this is an element of the base field, as $L$ is assumed to be a *functional*.